# image_item cannot be resolved "does not show in drop down and cannot be typed"

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As stated above `image_item` cannot be written incorrectly and isn't accepted, everything else seems fine but has this changed in a recent version? I'm trying to pull images down from Firebase to be displayed on the screen as a list.  This is the suspect code. As mentioned when trying to enter image_item I do not see the selection and it blanks out as red. The dependencies should be fine and all the necessary imports. The notes I have been recently done so maybe I'm missing something super obvious.

```
public class ImageListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<UploadFeature> imgList;
private ListView listView;
private ImageListAdapter adapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_list);
    imgList = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewImage);

    //should show the progress of action
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    progressDialog.show();

    mDatabaseRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(MainActivity.FB_DATABASE_PATH);

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                UploadFeature img = snapshot.getValue(UploadFeature.class);
                imgList.add(img);
            }

            adapter = new 
ImageListAdapter(ImageListActivity.this,R.layout.image_item, imgList);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
}
}
```

added JSON

```
  {
  "project_info": {
  "project_number": "43895898436",
  "firebase_url": "https://newattempt-59e4c.firebaseio.com",
  "project_id": "newattempt-59e4c",
  "storage_bucket": "newattempt-59e4c.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
  {
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:43895898436:android:8e25253f09f2f157",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.example.david.newattempt"
    }
  },
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "43895898436- 
   bnhm5lkgkjqcqdlo0hqc19ri3tu734qd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 3
    }
  ],
  "api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": "AIzaSyDzNZJfyJORvpX67jac_mc5vkEWzh9ybSg"
    }
  ],
  "services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 1
    },
    "appinvite_service": {
      "status": 1,
      "other_platform_oauth_client": []
    },
    "ads_service": {
      "status": 2
     }
   }
 }
],
"configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: New to this so I'm a little unsure what you would mean by database structure. Sorry.

Comment: Meaning the JSON file that can be downloadd from the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

Comment: Swapped image_item for image_layout and did a clean build and it worked, although be it a bit sluggish

Comment: `MainActivity.FB_DATABASE_PATH` is pointing to?